# How to convert mac addr to int using awk?

Tags: shell, awk, integer, ip, mac-address

Input:

```
192.168.0.1 aa:bb:cc:00:11:22 192.168.0.1 aa:00:bb:11:cc:22
192.168.10.11 2a:bb:cc:20:11:22 192.168.10.11 aa:02:bb:21:cc:22
```

Output:

```
3232235521 187723558162722 3232235521 186920115227682
3232238091 46986071904546 3232238091 186928706210850
```

I know how to convert mac to int (hex -> int) in python3
: `mac = int(mac.replace(':', ''), 16)`
But I cant' apply this method in shell. Also don't know about IP to Int.

I want to using awk, like this:

```
awk '{$1,$3=??, $2,$4=???}' tmpfile > newfile
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU awk for strtonum():

```
$ echo 'aa:bb:cc:00:11:22' | awk '{gsub(/:/,""); print strtonum("0x"$0)}'
187723558162722

$ echo '192.168.0.1' | awk '{split($0,o,/[.]/); print o[1]*256^3 + o[2]*256^2 + o[3]*256 + o[4]}'
3232235521
```

```
$ cat tst.awk
function ip2int(ip,  o) { split(ip,o,/[.]/); return o[1]*256^3 + o[2]*256^2 + o[3]*256 + o[4] }
function mac2int(mac)   { gsub(/:/,"",mac); return strtonum("0x"mac) }
{ print ip2int($1), mac2int($2), ip2int($3), mac2int($4) }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
3232235521 187723558162722 3232235521 186920115227682
3232238091 46986071904546 3232238091 186928706210850
```

Comment: Can I use this method like in this pattern?
: `awk '{$2=gsub(/:/,""); print strtonum("0x"$0)}' tmp`
But its outputs are '0 ...'

Comment: @matiii `gsub()` returns how many replacements it made, not the modified string. I added the full code to get the output you want from the input you posted.

Comment: Now I see. I didn't figure out about your script(tst.awk). Now I found out! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Perl one-liner

```
$ cat matii.txt
192.168.0.1 aa:bb:cc:00:11:22 192.168.0.1 aa:00:bb:11:cc:22
192.168.10.11 2a:bb:cc:20:11:22 192.168.10.11 aa:02:bb:21:cc:22

perl -pe ' s/(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+).(\d+)/$1*256**3+$2*256**2+$3*256+$4/ge; s/://g ; s/\S+\s+\K(\S+)/hex($1)/ge;' matii.txt
3232235521 187723558162722 3232235521 186920115227682
3232238091 46986071904546 3232238091 186928706210850
```

Answer (score -1):

The Perl equivalent of

```py
mac = int(mac.replace(':', ''), 16)
```

is

```perl
$mac = hex( $max =~ s/://rg )
```

---

A solution:

```sh
perl -nle'print join " ", unpack "N Q> N Q>", pack "( C4 xx(H2)6 )2", /[0-9a-fA-F]+/g'
```

[Specifying file to process to Perl one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41742890/589924)

---

A clearer solution:

```sh
perl -lane'
   sub ipv4_to_dec { unpack "N", pack "C4", split /\./, $_[0] }
   sub mac_to_dec { hex( $_[0] =~ s/://rg ) }
   print join " ",
      ipv4_to_dec($F[0]), mac_to_dec($F[1]),
      ipv4_to_dec($F[2]), mac_to_dec($F[3]);
'
```

or

```sh
perl -ple'
   sub ipv4_to_dec { unpack "N", pack "C4", split /\./, $_[0] }
   sub mac_to_dec { hex( $_[0] =~ s/://rg ) }
   s{\G(\s*)(\S+)(\s+)(\S+)}{ $1 . ipv4_to_dec($2) . $3 . mac_to_dec($4) }eg;
'
```