# How does `print readline` differ from `$line = readline; print $line`?

Tags: perl, text, text-processing

I wrote a script that prints the current and subsequent line after a match, however, I've noticed a difference between two ways of using the `readline` return value.

This works as intended:

```sh
$ echo $'H1\na\nb\nH2\na\nb' | perl -ne 'if (/^H/) { print; print $line = readline }'
H1
a
H2
a
```

However, this doesn't:

```sh
$ echo $'H1\na\nb\nH2\na\nb' | perl -ne 'if (/^H/) { print; print readline }'
H1
a
b
H2
a
b
```

instead, it prints all the lines. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`print` takes a list argument, and puts `readline()` in list context. Hence it exhausts all of the lines. When you use scalar assignment with `$line =`  it is in scalar context, and will only read 1 line.

Read more about context [here](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata#Context).

Answer (score 3):

The context in which `readline` is called is different.

In `$line = readline`, `=` is the scalar assignment operator, and it evaluates its operands in scalar context. In scalar context, `readline` returns a single line.

`print`, on the other hand, accepts an expression which it evaluates in list context. In list context, `readline` returns all remaining lines.

Equivalent:<sup>[1]</sup>

- `$line = readline; print $line;`
- `print $line = readline;`
- `print scalar(readline);`

---

1. If `$line` isn't magical. Except for the effect on `$line`.

Comment: hi ikegami.. need your help in reviewing my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68868817/how-to-convert-mac-addr-to-int-using-awk/68876184#68876184  could you pls suggest improvements

Comment: ok thanks.. just want to know if 2 perl could be combined